# Проблемы с передачей переменных в docker-compose cli

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Всем привет.

Есть у меня такой docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  redis2:
    image: redis:5
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:6379
```

Я его запускаю с помощью cli: `docker-compose run -e PORT=6379 -d redis2`

Получаю ошибку:  The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Но какого? Это должно работать согласно документации...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Флаг `-e` в команде `docker-compose` позволяет устанавливать переменные окружения внутри контейнера (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/), т.е. запустите контейнер и выполните в нем `echo $PORT`, тогда вы и увидете нужно значение.

Если же вам нужно передать порт в `docker-compose` команду (чтобы это использовать в `docker-compose.yml` файле как параметр), вы можете задать значение этого параметра перед командой, например (этот синтаксис работает в bash на Linux/WSL/MacOS, для CMD/PowerShell скорее всего нужно что-то другое):

```
PORT=6379 docker-compose run -d redis2
```

или если вам нужно определить переменную отдельно, то можно:

```
export PORT=6379
docker-compose run -d redis2
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так работает!